# Group Dates By Week: Open, Closed, Active

Tags: sql

Here is my scenario. I have a table like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ticket     |     start date      |    finish date             |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   123       |     1 apr 12        |        20 apr 12           |
|   124       |     4 apr 12        |        28 apr 12           |
|   125       |    16 apr 12        |         NULL               |
|   126       |    28 apr 12        |        4 may 12            |
|   127       |     2 may 12        |         NULL               |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I need to get a result set like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  week       |     opened      |    closed       |    active    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   5         |       3         |        2        |     50       |
|   6         |       4         |        5        |     49       |
|   7         |       2         |        6        |     45       |
|   8         |       5         |        4        |     46       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I want to see how many tickets were opened in a given week, how many were closed, and how many were simply active during that week (opened previously, and not closed yet).

I think I may have figured out how to derive the opened and closed, but I am really having trouble querying the active column out of this. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Adding info as requested.

This is for SQL.

The query I have thus far is like this, it doesn't include active yet:

```
    SELECT
    a.week,
    a.created,
    b.closed
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DATEPART(WEEK, t.[start date]) AS week,
        COUNT(t.[ticket]) AS opened
        FROM sqltable AS t
        WHERE [start date] > GETDATE() - 69 -- last 10 weeks
        GROUP BY
        DATEPART(WEEK, t.[start date])
    ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
        DATEPART(WEEK, t.[finish date]) AS week,
        COUNT(t.[ticket]) AS closed
        FROM sqltable AS t
        WHERE [finish date] > GETDATE() - 69 -- last 10 weeks
        GROUP BY
        DATEPART(WEEK, t.[finish date])
    ) AS b
    ON a.week = b.week
    ORDER BY a.week;
```

Comment: Add what queries you've tried to the question

Comment: which DBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: how are you determining the week number?

Answer (score 1):

In any database, you can do this with a correlated subquery.  However, date functions are not the same across databases, so let me assume you know how to do this.

```
select weeknum, sum(startweek) as starts, sum(endweek) as ends,
       (select count(*) as numstarts
        from t ts
        where DATEPART(WEEK, ts.[start date]) <= weeknum and
              datepart(week, ts.[end date]) >= weeknum
       ) as actives
from ((select DATEPART(WEEK, t.[start date]) AS weeknum, 1 as startweek, 0 endweek,
              t.[start date] as startdate, NULL as enddate
       from t
      ) union all
      (select DATEPART(WEEK, t.[end date]) AS weeknum, 0 as startweek, 1 as endweek,
              NULL, t.[end date] as enddate
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by weeknum
order by 1
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 (or Oracle), then you can also do this with cumulative sums.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to do this using IF statement and generating +1 for each true result of the cumulative sum :

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%U") as week,
  SUM(IF(startdate<>'', 1, 0)) as opened,
  SUM(IF(enddate<>'', 1, 0)) as closed,
  SUM(IF(startdate<>'' AND enddate<>'',  0, 1)) as active
FROM ticket
GROUP BY week;
```

The query is much simple hope it will helps

Tried this in MySQL 5.6 the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96a24a/17)